# How to install .exe with enabling "I agree to the license terms and conditions" in windows cmd

Tags: windows, powershell, cmd, azure-active-directory

I am trying to install **Azure Ad Password Protection proxy** executable file using cmd command.

`cmd /s "C:\AzureADPasswordProtectionProxySetup.exe"   AGREETOLICENSE=“yes”` but this command is hangs and doesn't install anything.

Below is what I want to enable and install using command prompt.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are looking for is how to do an unattended installation. Microsoft's page "Plan and deploy on-premises Azure Active Directory Password Protection"[1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/authentication/howto-password-ban-bad-on-premises-deploy#install-and-configure-the-proxy-service) says the right command is:

```
AzureADPasswordProtectionProxySetup.exe /quiet
```

Hope I was able to help.

[1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/authentication/howto-password-ban-bad-on-premises-deploy#install-and-configure-the-proxy-service) [Microsoft Docs, August 25th, 2022. "Install and configure the proxy service" on *Plan and deploy on-premises Azure Active Directory Password Protection*. Microsoft Entra. Retrieved on August 29th, 2022.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/authentication/howto-password-ban-bad-on-premises-deploy#install-and-configure-the-proxy-service)

Comment: OP indicated it's an executable. Would your advice be to use an MSI?

Comment: Yeah, I noticed right away that I accidentally used the instructions to install the Agent, which is an .msi. But the response has been edited to reflect the correct file, now.